# HTC U Play - No root access after flashing insecure boot image

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, root-access

This is my first post here and I hope I am posting it in the right place.

I have modified stock boot image following a few guides on XDA. Now running "id" command in adb shell returns:

```
root@htc_alpine_uhl:/ # id
id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) context=u:r:shell:s0
```

But I am unable to mount /system as rw or even execute simple tasks like "ls /data/media/0" etc.

I am trying to do all this because there is no custom recovery or any other root process available for this device until now.

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated. I am new with this stuff so please bear with me.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to root your phone is to flash a custom recovery then install SuperSU zip, modding the boot will not give you root access until there is a real su binary on the system

Have you checked if su command works on your phone or not?

Comment: True, but custom recovery is not available and I don't think I will be able to compile it myself. :(

su command doesn't work. But if shell is running as "root" already, shouldn't it elevate privileges?

Comment: This issue happened to me too with Production builds, altering the boot image was not enough, it shows that you are root # on the adb shell but in reality you have not full root privileges, maybe it has a relation with the build flavor: "user-debug" "engineer" or "production" build.

Comment: Guess I should start working on trying to port TWRP then. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Exactly,  for MTK based phones it's very easy to port them, but I don't know if it's the same for other SoCs, I wish you good luck, and don't forget to post a valid answer if you encountered it in the futur for this question.